# How to Unset foreach

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, foreach, unset

I have an Array with entries and use foreach to output this like this:

```
foreach ($entries as $entry):

            $mail = $entry['53'];

            if ($mail == $CurrentUserMail) {

                    // Display entry from this user..

             }

endforeach;
```

The entry values can be `$entry['23']` or `$entry['47.2']` or whatever. And when looping through the foreach some entries may not have any "23" or "47.2" and then keeps this value from previous entry.

I have tried to use `$entry = '';` and the end but is does not unset all the values.

How can I start with empty values for `$entry` as the foreach loops?

Comment: `foreach ($entries as &$entry)` perhaps.

Comment: Sorry that did no do it. Thanks anyway @bishop

Comment: `foreach ($entries as $key => $entry) { unset($entries[$key]); }` perhaps.

Answer (score 2):

Solved it myself. The problem was not in unset the foreach. In the function I had  used

```
if ($entry['40']) { $funcs .= 'Someting ..' }
if ($entry['42']) { $funcs .= '.. someting more ..' }
if ($entry['44']) { $funcs .= '.. someting else ..' }
```

and the solution was of course to unset the $funcs!

Thanks @Bishop for your tips, it did help me as well to unset the `$entry`.